# Get category if one of its parents is a determined ID in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a parent category called test1 and another called test2. Inside both categories exists a child category called child1. And inside these subcategories exists another one called child 2.

I need to search for a category by its url_key. This url key may be the same between the category dependent of test1 and test2, so I need to filter by its first parent id.

This is how I do it now:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                     ->getCollection ()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect ('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter ('url_key', $category_urlkey)
                     ->getFirstItem ();
```

How do I put an Attribute Filter to filter by its first level parent?

Comment: Do you have your parent category id? I did not get what you are passing in $category_urlkey.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have the parent category id and $category_urlkey for example would be child1, this is the url key that was configured in magento like the slug, but magento allows to have several of this values the same in different categories, that's why I need to return just the category dependent of the given first level category parent